# div elements with display: inline are hidden

Tags: css

If i am right display:inline should display div on the same line without any line break. This is my web page where display:inline simply makes my div invisible:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .body{
    max-width:3072px;
    min-width:3072px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#293231;

   }

   .page1{
    background:url('Main.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:1024px;
    height:211px;


   }

   .page2{
    background:url('Page2.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:1024px;
    height:211px;
    display:inline;
   }

   .page3{
    background:url('Page3.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:1024px;
    height:211px;
    display:inline;
   }

   .wrapper{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
   }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body class="body">

  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="page1">

   </div>
   <div class="page2">

   </div>
   <div class="page3">

   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I can see divs with class = page1, but page2 and page3 are invisible.

Comment: Perhaps you just forgot to include it here, but use a proper [Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling) to trigger standards mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-block element can't have height/width specified like that (and with no content inside, it'll have nothing to give it size) - instead you want `inline-block`, like this:

```
display: inline-block;
```

[You can see a full list of options for `display` here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: right, but inline-block unfortunately doesn't work on all browsers, but on the most. As far as I know it doesn't really work on IE6 and FF2. You can use `display: -moz-inline-block` to make it work on FF2. In IE6 `display: inline-block` only works on elements which are naturally inline. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @snootles - You want an advanced effect...you need an advanced browser :) If you want IE6, use a span, then use `inline-block` and add the mozilla tag as well...this is a bit hacky, if you you want effects that post-date the browsers, it's your best option.  As a side note: are you *sure* the OP needs to support those browsers?  Given a choice, I wouldn't...and don't unless needed.

Comment: …or in the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display).

Comment: Sorry Nick, i would like to interrupt your discussion but what is the meaning of OP?

Comment: @Nitesh - "Original Poster" - you :)

Comment: @Marcel - I try and refer to a site that's updated, while the spec is the best source(of course!), what happens when this gets googled later, and [the next spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#the-lsquo) takes effect? :) I'm trying to be aware that this answer while serving to answer the question *now*, will be here much *later*, and information/links may be outdated then :)

Comment: Yeah you are right, i don't use it. IE6 is crap for me. Even my yahoo mails didn't open in it and frequently i faced crashing issues. I use FF 3.5 and IE8 so not a problem for me.

Comment: @Nick Craver: If you feel need to *support* some *browsers*, your web page is broken. The real question is: do you really need that latest browser feature? Does it increase the sales? If the page is unreadable on some browsers, that will definitely decrease the sales.

Comment: @PauliL - You're making the false assumption that all sites are **public** sites, and that I don't know exactly which browsers my users have.  *If* that was the case, and it's not for me, what product are you selling?  Demographics matter here.

Comment: @snootles If you use **`div#someId { display: inline; zoom: 1; }`** for IE6 and IE7 (conditional comments, mustn't target IE8 as this version is OK), then your layout will be perfectly fine. For Fx 2, it's better to use `-moz-inline-stack`. There's still some glitch 20% of the time with Fx2 (no selection and no clicks possible) and in this case `#someId` must have an unique div child which contains your original elements. But well Fx2 is soooo old ...

Comment: You have a point, but even then I wouldn't link to w3schools.com. That site contains many fundamental misconceptions (e.g., look at [this page](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/#global_confusion)). I just like the [mentioned page on Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) more, giving a clearer picture of browser differences (but it's also a matter of personal preference, of course, and strangely enough I can't access w3schools.com directly, perhaps my IP is blocked).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `display: inline-block` [is not supported by older versions of IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html). You can do this by floating your three inner `div` tags left, and undoing the float on the containing element. Here is the complete example (see my comments for the relevant changes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .body { max-width:3072px; min-width:3072px; margin:0px auto; background:#293231; }

            .page1{ background:url('Main.jpg') no-repeat; }

            .page2 { background:url('Page2.jpg') no-repeat; }

            .page3{ background:url('Page3.jpg') no-repeat; }

            /* These next two lines are my changes. */
            /* Float these guys left */.page1, .page2, .page3 { width:1024px; height:211px; float: left; }
            /* Add overflow: hidden to "undo" the floating */.wrapper{ overflow: hidden; width:100%; height:auto; }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="body">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="page1">

            </div>
            <div class="page2">

            </div>
            <div class="page3">

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saying it's *not* supported is inaccurate, it's not *completely* supported, like most things in IE.